# Cross-Platform Property Animation API for C#

Tags: c#, api, animation, time, properties

I'm searching for an API that would do something equivalent to the Property Animation framework from android. I searched but didn't find anything relevant, I don't want a big library as QT or WPF (isn't cross-platform anyway), the windows animation manager seems a little complex and didn't look like it was compatible with mono.

I found some topics speaking about animations, but the answers pointed to SDL links or things like that. In my case, I'm already doing the rendering part and only need something simple and fast to change the properties of objects as time passes, so I'm not searching for a graphic animation API or something like that.

The Property Animation framework from android is the best example of what I want (from what I saw) but didn't manage to find something good, simple and little. Maybe I'm searching the wrong terms, or maybe I don't see what I want to do from the right angle, or maybe it's just really simple to do.

I can write one, but I wanted to see if it didn't exist first.

Little clarification: By cross-platform I mean Windows, Linux and Mac; it's a desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my question was voted down without explanation, I didn't knew really what do to so I made my own little thing like this:

```
// class TransitionValue inherit from Transition<T>
// Length is the length of the transition in seconds.
// Additional parameters : Restart, Rewind
// Events: OnFinish, OnRestart, Onrewind
TransitionValue value = new TransitionValue(startValue, endValue, length)

// Update with ElapsedTime
value.Update(stopWatch.Elapsed);

// Choose the function to use.
Console.WriteLine("F(x) = {0}", value.Linear());
```

I was searching for something simple to use and was sure it already existed but I didn't found exactly what I wanted.. anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target WP8, Windows Store, WPF or Silverlight, I think you are looking for [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. You can write it by hand on Visual Studio or with [Blend](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flIbZ_1dJZ0).

Example with a `ColorAnimation` from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

XAML

```
<StackPanel MouseLeftButtonUp="Rectangle_Tapped">
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
    <!-- Animate the background color of the canvas from red to green over 4 seconds. -->
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="mySolidColorBrush"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
            From="Red" To="Green" Duration="0:0:4" />
    </Storyboard>
</StackPanel.Resources>
<StackPanel.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="mySolidColorBrush" Color="Red" />
</StackPanel.Background>
</StackPanel>
```

C#

```
// When the user taps the rectangle, the animation begins.
private void Rectangle_Tapped(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    myStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been precise enough, by cross-platform I meant Windows Linux and Mac. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: No problem. I think you can look into Xamarin. They can have something for you. I never use it so I cant help you with it.

Comment: Xamarin looks good, but it's too big for what I want. Still, thank you for your time!